# Is there anything wrong with this VBA Code?

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to run this:

```
Sub cumleng()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
For i = 5 To 64
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        For j = 3 To 64
            If Cells(j, 9) = Left(Cells(i, 9), Len(Cells(i, 9)) - 1) Then
                If IsEmpty(Cells(j, 6)) Then
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    Cells(i, 6) = Cells(j, 6) + Cells(i, 2)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

However, it's not working as expected. Nothing is being written to Cells (i,6). Help?

Here's what's supposed to happen:
For every row, in column B there's a number, and in column 6 there's an ID. I want to output, for every row, the cumulative sum of the number in B for that row and every parent row. A row's ID is equal to the parent's ID with one more digit added to the end. I want the cumulative sum to be used only if the branch has a number in column B, and only if the parent has a cumulative length in column F. As it is, nothing is being outputted in column F.

Comment: Please show sample data in columns B, F and I. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Depends. What is it **supposed** to do?

Comment: Your title could use some work. I was tempted to answer, "Dunno, you tell us."  Hint: if you never google something like "looking for VBA code with something wrong with it" then you shouldn't title your posts that way. :-)

Comment: Please post sample data and where your code is tripping up. Telling us what you've tried to fix the problem would be a bonus too!

Comment: Are you sure you want `Exit Sub` and not `Exit For` in the inner loop?

Answer (score 0):

The number **123** does not equal a text string that only looks like **"123"**. The Left function is returning text that looks like the first Len-1 digits of a number (e.g. **1234** becomes **"123"**); the cell contains a true number (e.g. **123**).

Try it as,

```
'with both as numbers
If Cells(j, 9) = Int(Cells(i, 9) / 10) Then
'alternate with both as text
If CStr(Cells(j, 9)) = Left(Cells(i, 9), Len(Cells(i, 9)) - 1) Then
```